# How to use Keras in repl.it

Tags: keras, replit

I am using repl.it and I want to use keras in repl.it environment, however when I used the following:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
```

I received the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'

I understand that I need to install keras package in repl.it but do not have any idea how can I do this. Can anyone please suggest any idea for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the package logo on the toolbar on the left hand side (depicted below), then a search bar appears where you can add new dependencies, e.g. Keras.

[image: Package logo]

Comment: Thanks 
Following your advice, i have installed TensorFlow and Keras in the Installed packages.I can see the following packages have installed such as tensorflow. however, it still gives  following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow # only need this for repl.it
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

Any suggestion

Comment: It seems that this is a known problem with tensorflow, looking at the replit forums. My guess is that it has something to do with the external code those packages run, or maybe replit have made a conscious decision that they don't want their servers used for deep learning (with all the attendant enormous resource costs) and so have disabled these specifically. My suggestion would be to use Google Colab instead for online deep learning (with the advantage that you can train on GPUs if you want to)